# Determine when touch gesture leaves target element

Tags: javascript, ios, html, touch

I have some HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #f00" class="t"></div>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #0f0" class="t"></div>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #00f" class="t"></div>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 10px;" id="indicator"></div>
```

How can I write JavaScript that will make `#indicator`'s `background` color whatever the background of `#x`, `#y`, or `#z` is while a finger is touching the rectangle around `x`, `y`, and `z`?

I can do

```
$(".t").on('touchstart', function() {
  $("#indicator").css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
});
```

which does change the color, but can't figure out how to turn the color back to `auto` once the finger has left the constrains of the `div.t`.

(I know about `touchend`, but I want it to revert to the default color as soon as the finger has left the rectangle, not as soon as the finger is picked up.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `touchmove` event.

```
$(".t").on('touchmove', function(e) {
  var tx=e.targetTouches[0].pageX,
      ty=e.targetTouches[0].pageY;

  if(!SOME_FUNCTION_TO_CHECK_IF_THE_TOUCH_IS_IN_THE_ELEMENT(x,y,e.target)){
    //Remove the color
  }


});
```

In the example above the three arguments for the function are the x-coordinate of the touch, the y-coordinate of the touch and the touched element `e.target`.
To give you a basic idea for the "collision" function, you can determine the actual position, width and height of an element with `element.getBoundingClientRect()`([More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)).

Take a look at this: [touch events](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/).

I hope that helps.